# Accessing sqlite database and showing graph on browser

Tags: javascript, java, sqlite

I am working on an academic project which aims the following:

1. I have a sqlite database which contains data in a tabular format
2. I want to access the sqlite database and draw graph based on the values of two columns.
3. This graph I have to show on a browser.

For this I am taking following approach:

1. I have written a java program (shown below) which accesses the sqlite database and shows the graph.
2. Now my next step is to connect my java program with javascript and show the graph on a browser.

First of all I would like to know whether my approach is correct and if yes, please suggest the way how to move ahead.I am not versed with programming languages so please help me with your esteemed support.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

import java.sql.*;
import org.jfree.ui.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.data.*;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.BarRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.jdbc.JDBCCategoryDataset;


public class sqliteConnection {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable table;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

    public static Connection dbConnect(){
        Connection c = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:D:\\Project\\db.sqlite3");
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return c;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sqliteConnection window = new sqliteConnection();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    Connection connection = null;
    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public sqliteConnection() {
        connection = sqliteConnection.dbConnect();
        initialize();

        }


    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1260, 698);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(70, 125, 1015, 411);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Load Data");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    String query="select * from mc_measurement";
                    PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        btnNewButton.setBounds(465, 45, 156, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Load Graph");
        btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    String query="select id,res from mc_measurement";
                    JDBCCategoryDataset dataset = new JDBCCategoryDataset(sqliteConnection.dbConnect(),query);
                    JFreeChart chart=ChartFactory.createLineChart("Trend Result", "id","res", dataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,false,true,true);
                    BarRenderer renderer = null;
                    CategoryPlot plot = null;
                    renderer = new BarRenderer();
                    ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Trend Result",chart);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setSize(400,650);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        btnNewButton_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(825, 46, 150, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you save your `graph` as an image, then you will be able to load it into a browser.  otherwise consider using a JS Graph library like https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts/index-en.html

Comment: Try [JDBC with MS Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbt582h(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Sorry, I wrongly read MS Access instead of SQLite

Comment: Javascript does not need Java to connect to a database. Javascript also has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: Please shere any reference where I can learn how to connect sqlite with java script

Answer (score 1):

### Existing database visualizers

You can use one of the existing tools for building charts from the database, e.g. [Redash](https://redash.io/) (more advanced) or my own open-source web app [sqliteviz](https://github.com/lana-k/sqliteviz). In the latter you can just drop your database file, run an SQL query and build a chart using `Plotly.js`:
[image: Image from Gyazo]

### Build your own database visualizer

If you need to have a chart on your own website or for some reason existing tools don't suit you then here is how to build your own.

#### Working with database

First of all you need a tool to read a database and run queries in javascript. Use [sql.js](https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js/) for that. I assume that the database file is not supposed to be chosen by a user. So you can take it with fetch. Here is an example of usage:

```js
const config = {
  locateFile: filename => (
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sql.js/1.5.0/sql-wasm.wasm'
  )
}

const sqlPromise = initSqlJs(config)

// Replace URL with a path to your database
const dataPromise = fetch((
  'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/database-js-sqlite@1.3.0/test.sqlite'
))
  .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())

Promise.all([sqlPromise, dataPromise])
  .then(([SQL, buf]) => {
    // Create a database from a file
    const db = new SQL.Database(new Uint8Array(buf))
    document.getElementById('btn').onclick = () => {
      // Run SELECT query
      const res = db.exec('SELECT * FROM states limit 10')
      const result = document.getElementById('result')
      result.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res[0], null, 4)
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sql.js/1.5.0/sql-wasm.js">
</script>

<button id="btn">RUN: SELECT * FROM states</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

If your queries are slow `sql.js` also can be used as a web worker. See its documentation for more details.

#### Using `react-chart-editor`

[`react-chart-editor`](https://github.com/plotly/react-chart-editor) is a great option if you need to have an interactive chart on your web page. By the way this component is used in sqliteviz. `react-chart-editor` is a React component. But you can use it inside another framework with a bridge (e.g. in Vue.js with [vuera](https://github.com/akxcv/vuera)). Here is the simplest example in React (see more examples [here](https://github.com/plotly/react-chart-editor/tree/master/examples)):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import plotly from 'plotly.js/dist/plotly';
import PlotlyEditor from 'react-chart-editor';
import 'react-chart-editor/lib/react-chart-editor.css';

const dataSources = {
  col1: [1, 2, 3],
  col2: [4, 3, 2],
  col3: [17, 13, 9],
};

const dataSourceOptions = Object.keys(dataSources).map(name => ({
  value: name,
  label: name,
}));

const config = {editable: true};

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {data: [], layout: {}, frames: []};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <PlotlyEditor
          data={this.state.data}
          layout={this.state.layout}
          config={config}
          frames={this.state.frames}
          dataSources={dataSources}
          dataSourceOptions={dataSourceOptions}
          plotly={plotly}
          onUpdate={(data, layout, frames) =>
            this.setState({data, layout, frames})
          }
          useResizeHandler
          debug
          advancedTraceTypeSelector
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

It will be an interactive chart editor where you can choose a type of chart and other settings. Here is an example of a line chart where `col1` goes on `x` axis and `col2` goes on `y`. [image: Image from Gyazo]

Note that `dataSources` has a different structure from an object that sql.js returns as a result set. You need to transform the result set in order to use it as data sources. See below the function `getDataSourcesFromResultSet` in the code snippet for the `Plotly.js` example.

#### Using only `Plotly.js`

If you need just build a chart without interactive editing you can use `Plotly.js`. From [Plotly.js guide](https://plotly.com/javascript/):

> Built on top of d3.js and stack.gl, Plotly.js is a high-level, declarative charting library. Plotly.js ships with over 40 chart types, including 3D charts, statistical graphs, and SVG maps.
> Plotly.js is free and open source and you can view the source, report issues or contribute on GitHub.

`Plotly.js` is actually used in `react-chart-editor`.
And below is an example of using `Plotly.js` and result set transformation:

```js
// Remember that sql.js returns result set in an object
// with two keys: columns and values, e.g.:
const resultSet = {
  columns:['month','amount'],
  values:[
    ['January', 1],
    ['February', 2],
    ['March', 4],
    ['April', 8],
    ['May', 16]
  ]
}

// But plotly expects "transposed" data: we need an array of months and
// an array with respective amount values. Let't create a function to
// transform the result set:
function getDataSourcesFromResultSet (resultSet) {
  if (!resultSet) {
    return {}
  }
  const dataSorces = {}
  const matrix = resultSet.values
  const [row] = matrix
  const transposedMatrix = row.map(
    (value, column) => matrix.map(row => row[column])
  )
  resultSet.columns.forEach((column, index) => {
    dataSorces[column] = transposedMatrix[index]
  })
  return dataSorces
}

const dataSorces = getDataSourcesFromResultSet(resultSet)

// And now use plotly:
TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');
Plotly.newPlot(
  TESTER,
  [{
    x: dataSorces.month,
    y: dataSorces.amount
  }],
  { margin: { t: 0 } }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="tester" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
```